# Create view with two object array from seperate collections in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, collections, view, inner-join

I want to create a view which fields are come from two different object array with seperate collections.For more explanation here is my code

```
    {
"_id" : ObjectId("5e4173cf51af9f555e64531c"),
"__v" : 0,
"createdDate" : ISODate("2020-02-24T08:33:24.100Z"),
"maxDate" : {
    "month" : 12,
    "year" : 2018
},
"modifiedDate" : ISODate("2020-02-24T08:33:33.025Z"),
"stockArray" : [ 
    {
        "purchase_bill_date" : "1/9/2017",
        "purchase_bill_series" : "A",
        "purchase_bill_item_no" : "419905",
        "stock_code" : "5372123-ANN",

    }, 
    {
        "purchase_bill_date" : "1/9/2017",
        "purchase_bill_series" : "A",
        "purchase_bill_item_no" : "419905",
        "stock_name" : "53743N-10-10S",

    }]
 }
```

and the other collection

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e4173cf51af9f555e64531c"),
"__v" : 0,
"yuklenimReports" : [ 
    {
        "purchase_bill_date" : "9/3/2018",
        "purchase_bill_series" : null,
        "purchase_bill_item_no" : "419905",
        ""stock_name" : "53743N-10-10S"
    }]
  }
```

i want to inner join purchase_bill_item_no and show the others.But i couldnt handle i spent too much hour to find the solution.Thanks for all help.

Comment: [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) are used in MongoDB to perform joins(*until unless your collection is not sharded*).

Comment: @vikscool i know but i couldnt handle that in array :(

Comment: Please post a document sample of the output as would want it.

Comment: If the array is your problem than what i would suggest is to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#unwind-aggregation) to expand your array on your child `collection` and in your `$lookup` use the `pipeline` stage to unwind  the parent collection's array then do your matching.